# Ejecutar .class desde consola

Tags: java, cmd, jvm

Estoy intentando ejecutar un `.class` desde la consola de windows, la estructura de carpetas donde tengo los class es la sigUiente:

```
C:
\Programa
        \com
            \index
                Clase.class
```

La clase Clase:

```
public class Clase {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hola");

    }
}
```

Desde el cmd:

```
C:\Programa> java -cp com/index/Clase
```

Al ejecutar esa sentencia me sale éste mensaje:

```
Sintaxis: java [-options] class [args...]
           (para ejecutar una clase)
   o  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (para ejecutar un archivo jar)
donde las opciones incluyen:
    -d32          usar un modelo de datos de 32 bits, si está disponible
    -d64          usar un modelo de datos de 64 bits, si está disponible
    -server       para seleccionar la VM "server"
                  La VM por defecto es server.

    -cp <ruta de acceso de búsqueda de clases de los directorios y los archivos zip/jar>
    -classpath <ruta de acceso de búsqueda de clases de los directorios y los archivos zip/jar>
                  Lista separada por ; de directorios, archivos JAR
                  y archivos ZIP para buscar archivos de clase.
    -D<nombre>=<valor>
                  definir una propiedad del sistema
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  activar la salida verbose
    -version      imprimir la versión del producto y salir
    -version:<valor>
                  Advertencia: Esta función está anticuada y se eliminará
                  en una versión futura.
                  es necesario que se ejecute la versión especificada
    -showversion  imprimir la versión del producto y continuar
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Advertencia: Esta función está anticuada y se eliminará
                  en una versión futura.
                  incluir/excluir JRE privados de usuario en la búsqueda de versión
    -? -help      imprimir este mensaje de ayuda
    -X            imprimir la ayuda sobre las opciones que no sean estándar
    -ea[:<nombre_paquete>...|:<nombre_clase>]
    -enableassertions[:<nombre_paquete>...|:<nombre_clase>]
                  activar afirmaciones con la granularidad especificada
    -da[:<nombre_paquete>...|:<nombre_clase>]
    -disableassertions[:<nombre_paquete>...|:<nombre_clase>]
                  desactivar afirmaciones con la granularidad especificada
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  activar afirmaciones del sistema
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  desactivar afirmaciones del sistema
    -agentlib:<nombre_bib>[=<opciones>]
                  cargar la biblioteca de agente nativa <nombre_bib>, como -agentlib:hprof
                  véase también -agentlib:jdwp=help y -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<nombre_ruta_acceso>[=<opciones>]
                  cargar biblioteca de agente nativa con el nombre de la ruta de acceso completa
    -javaagent:<ruta_acceso_jar>[=<opciones>]
                  cargar agente de lenguaje de programación Java, véase java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<ruta_acceso_imagen>
                  mostrar una pantalla de presentación con la imagen especificada
Consulte http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html para obtener más información.
```

No entiendo el motivo por el cual no me ejecuta la clase, ¿os suena éste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `-cp` simplemente especificas el `classpath`, es decir donde buscará la máquina virtual las clases y paquetes que le hacen falta para ejecutar tu programa. el último parámetro que le pasas a java es el nombre de la clase (paquete incluído) que quieres ejecutar.

Prueba con:

```
java -cp . com.index.Clase
```

Answer (score 1):

> java -cp com/index/Clase

1. `cp` indica que le pasas el classpath (una lista de directorios y/o jars). Por defecto su valor es el directorio en curso, así que ejecutas desde `C:\Programa` no lo necesitas, y si ejecutas desde otra ubicación es `-cp C:\Programa`.
2. La ruta a ejecutar no se pasa como la ruta a la clase, sino como el nombre completo de la clase en java. Es decir, `[packge1].[package2]...[Clase]`, o `com.index.Clase`.

   La idea es que con el CP indicas de donde debe la JVM cargar las clases y luego le indicas por nombre java (no por ruta) de cuál de las clases debe ejecutar el `main`.

Así pues

```
java [-cp C:\Programas] com.index.Clase
```

Answer (score 1):

Estando en el directorio donde se encuentra la clase:

```
java -cp . clase
```