# Ejecutar .class con libreria desde cmd

Tags: java, cmd, jvm

Antes he preguntado sobre como ejecutar un class [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181493/ejecutar-class-desde-consola)

En resumen la sentencia que me ha funcionado ha sido:

```
java -cp . com.index.Clase
```

El problema es que al ejecutar esa sentencia, me lanza una excepcion diciendo que no encuentra una de las varias librerías que uso:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Mirando por [stackOverflow en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file) he encontrado éste ejemplo:

```
java -cp c:\location_of_jar\myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass
```

En mi caso siguiendo la estructura:

```
C:
\Programa
 |   \com
 |       \index
 |           Clase.class
 jersey-client-1.9.1.jar
```

Ejecuto:

```
C:\Programa>java -cp jersey-client-1.9.1.jar . com.index.Clase
```

Me vuelve a lanzar la misma excepción que al principio.

Por cierto no sé muy bien qué significa el `.` pero sin él no me funciona.

Comment: Desde el root del proyecto: `java -cp ;jersey-client-1.9.1.jar com.index.Clase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar librerías externas hay que incluirlas también al *classpath*, esto depende por supuesto de la estructura del proyecto; tomando la del ejemplo que mencionas, hay que situarse en la raíz del proyecto `Programa` y luego:

`java -cp ;jersey-client-1.9.1.jar com.index.Clase`

Después de `java -cp` va el lugar donde se encuentran los `.class` y también las librerías externas que la app vaya a utilizar (*colocando un separador* `;` *para Windows* o `:` *para *nix*).

Para este caso especifico, en donde el paquete `com.index` esta directamente en el *root* del proyecto, al igual que el JAR, basta con 'dejar en blanco' la ubicación de los `.class`, separar y luego poner el nombre del JAR.

Ahora si por ejemplo suponemos que el paquete `com.index` estuviera dentro de un directorio `org/user` y a su vez el JAR le perteneciera a un directorio `lib/tools`:

```
Programa
|--org
|  |--user
|     |--com
|        |--index
|           |-- Clase.class
|--lib
|  |--tools
|     |-- jersey-client-1.9.1.jar
```

la instrucción por consola (*Windows*) seria equivalente a:

`java -cp org\user;lib\tools\jersey-client-1.9.1.jar com.index.Clase`